# What, which process interprets Escape Sequences in programming?

Tags: c, string, escaping

From where to where, through which process recognize backslash as an escaping character and makes it work together with letters? (e.g. \n, \t ...

In Wikipedia, following sentence is written:

> C interprets \n inside a literal as a newline character, whatever that may be on the target system:

SO, which means, each programming languages offer "escaping" and the code (like "\n") will be interpreted to assembly (like Go TO Next Line)?

Comment: There are lots of different programs that interpret escape sequences — there is no one process (program) that does so.  The programs that _do_ interpret escape sequences typically have their own idiosyncracies about which escape sequences they interpret and not infrequently do it slightly differently from other programs.

Comment: When quoting from another source, provide a specific URL for that source or a full bibliographic citation.

Comment: ```will be interpreted to assembly (like Go TO Next Line)?``` not necessarily. In ```NASM```, for instance, this does not work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for letting me know that! Actually this is probably the first time for me to post on stackoverflow. You helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The sentence you quote from Wikipedia is talking about interpretation done during translation of a C program. Translation of a C program is almost always done primarily by a compiler, and it is the compiler that examines the characters `\` and `n` and produces a newline character as a result.

Interpreting escape sequences inside string literals is a small part of interpreting and translating C programs and is not a significant step toward producing assembly language that implements the C program.

Comment: Quick and simple, understandable answer. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Some languages interpret or translate code into C. The C compiler apparently does modify string literals in source code, stripping out the trailing "\n", and converting them to "return characters" (octal 12, decimal 10) in the resulting binary, as seen by examining with `hexedit`.

It may be necessary to use `hexedit` to see when strings have changed, because disassemblers might convert the byte codes back into escape codes for display.

When a user inputs text, standard library functions may be used to convert escape sequences into their corresponding ASCII values for storage. Also, standard library output functions like `printf()`, `fprintf()`, etc. use special escape codes to format output before sending them to streams.

Using debugging tools to examine the journey that text takes can be an eye-opening experience.

Comment: I am confused. `The compiler apparently does modify string literals, stripping out` vs `with escape codes and sends them to printf()`. So the compiler strips them, or sends them unmodified?

Comment: Answer modified because I was fooled by my disassembler. Disassemblers can convert character codes back to '\' escape codes for display. Hexedit can't be tricked.

Comment: Hi ;) `When a user inputs text, standard library functions convert escape sequences into their corresponding ASCII values for storage` I do not follow. If I use `fgets` and type \x61<enter>, the program receives 5 bytes \x61<enter>, not a two bytes. `fprintf(), etc. can convert escape codes`  How to do that? Doing `char c[] = { '\\', 'x', '6', '1', '\0' }; printf(c);` prints `\x61` not `a`. printf did not interpret `\x`.

Answer (score 0):

> What, which process interprets Escape Sequences in programming?

The C compiler replaces (interprets) escape sequences by their binary representation.

`'\n'` means *the number* which we can represent by `10` in base 10 or `0x0A` in hex, when using a compiler which translates characters using ASCII or UNICODE encodings. `'\n'` is just a different *representation* of `10` or `0x0A`, it *means* the same - a *number* with such value.

For example, if you would be using a compiler which translates characters using EBCDIC encoding, `'\n'` would mean 0x15 in hex or 21 in base-10. ASCII is predominantly used today.

I am mentioning bases, to show different *representations* of the same number. (When using ASCII) `'\n'` *is* 10, and `'\0'` *is* 0 in C programming language, it is just a different way to write it.

> which means, each programming languages offer "escaping" and the code (like "\n") will be interpreted to assembly (like Go TO Next Line)?

No. `\n`, byte 0x0A in hex or 10 in base10, is interpreted specifically when sent to an ANSI compatible terminal as an "action" to move the cursor to the next line.

A different terminal, not compatible with ANSI or ECMA-48, may do something else. For a different program, it might mean something else. For us humans, `\n` means slash followed by `n` and we do no special action.

Assembly language itself is inanimate. The assembly *compiler* might again *translate* `\n` two characters in the assembly source code to its representation in a chosen encoding when translating assembly language to machine code instructions. The logic inside the machine instructions contains bytes, and it up to those instructions what actions the number 10 results in.